# How to Reference A Jenkins Global Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

After reviewing the [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), a number of questions here on SO, and trying a dozen or so different script configurations, I cannot figure out how to reference a shared Groovy library. I've added the library like so:

[image: Jenkins Library Config]

This appears to be working. I'm referencing the script like so:

[image: Jenkins script reference in build]

You can see the error message therein:

> Script1: 1: unable to resolve class Library ,  unable to find class
>   for annotation @ line 1, column 1.     @Library('sonarQubeAPI')_

The script code, not I think it matters, looks like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class SonarQubeAPI{
    static string getVersion(){
        return "1.0";
    }

    static void getSonarStatus(projectKey){
        def sonarQubeUserToken = "USERTOKEN";
        def projectStatusUrl = "pathtosonarqube/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=" + projectKey;

        println("Retrieving project status for " + projectKey);

        def json = getJson(sonarQubeUserToken, projectStatusUrl);

        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(json);

        println(object.projectStatus.status);
    }

    static string getJson(userToken, url){
        def authString  = "${userToken}:".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString();

        def conn = url.toURL().openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic ${authString}" );

        return conn.content.text;
    }
}
```

I'm probably just a magic character off, but I can't seem to lock it down.

Comment: System Groovy Script is not the same as Jenkins Pipeline

Comment: Yeah, I tried the simple Groovy script and got the same result.

Comment: @StephenKing - do you think I'm just using this feature wrong? I'm trying to share a script that needs to be executed across several builds, and not just copy and paste the code.

Comment: Shared libraries are a feature of Jenkins Pipelines, not of Jenkins (core) itself. You can use them only in Pipeline jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) are a feature of Jenkins Pipelines, not of Jenkins (core) itself. You can use them only in Pipeline jobs (and child types like Multibranch Pipeline).